# .HTACCESS redirect /calendar to /events

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect all traffic from **/calendar** to **/events**.

`www.domain.com/calendar/sales` to `redirect to www.domain.com/events/sales`

So I need to replace **calendar** with **events** anyone who goes to the main `calendar` page, `www.domain.com/calendar` will be redirect to `www.domain.com/events`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the rewrite rule

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/calendar.*$
   RewriteRule /calendar((/.*)?)$ /events$1 [QSA,R=301]
```

In your VirtualHost context.

You need to load mod_rewrite for it to work.

Comment: works, but redirects url's that contain the segment 'calendar' in it, for example: http://www.domain.com/sales/calendar, redirects to http://www.domain.com/events, I only want to redirect if the word 'calendar' is the segment 1

Comment: I have made change, try again.

Comment: not redirecting /sales/calendar like before, which is good, but it is not redirecting /calendar/sales either.

Comment: you have put this .htaccess or virtualhost context??

Comment: htaccess, this looks like it works RewriteRule ^calendar/(.*)$ /events/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: in .htaccess at root that will work. rewriterule for Server, virtual config are slightly different from .htaccess, directory context

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^calendar/(.*)$ events/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Best

Marco

Comment: This doesn't deserve downvote. It will work if you put it in .htaccess of DocumentRoot, but wont work if it /calendar .. +1

Comment: this looks like it works RewriteRule ^calendar/(.*)$ /events/$1 [R=301,L]